# Phone Numbers in separate lines in UNIX

Tags: regex, unix

In UNIX----

I have a Sample file i want all the phone numbers starting from 987 in another file as a list, 
that means if in single row there are 2 phone numbers they should be in separate lines.

Sample File Contents

ajfhvjfdhvjdfb jfbhfb fg  9871177454 9563214578 shgfsehfgvhb vhf 9877745212
sjdjfgsfhvg b 9874789645 sfjkvhbjfbg  shgfhbfg 2563145278
9874561231

Comment: #!/bin/sh
grep 987??????? Desktop\SampleDoc.txt > ABC.doc (As ? only matches for a single value, but the issue here can be "?" can take character value as well. Also, not getting how to take in different lines.) @VadimLanda

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
echo "ajfhvjfdhvjdfb jfbhfb fg 9871177454 9563214578 shgfsehfgvhb vhf 9877745212 sjdjfgsfhvg b 9874789645 sfjkvhbjfbg shgfhbfg 2563145278 9874561231" > sample.txt

egrep -o '987([0-9]+)' sample.txt
```

returns,

```
9871177454
9877745212
9874789645
9874561231
```

or to be specific for 10 digit phone numbers,

```
egrep -o '987([0-9]{7})' sample.txt
```

returns similar results.